# When running go env GOPATH is shown as something different than what I have set in my environment variables?

Tags: go, gopath

First of all I'm really new to Go. I've been struggling with this issue for about a week now and its driving me crazy (because of this issue its not recognizing my packages). I have set up my GOPATH in environment variables:

[image: Image of the GOPATH that I set in System Env Variables]

When I run go env at the command line, I see something different being returned:

[image: The image of what I see when I run go env]

**The error I see when it can't find my package:**

cannot find package "pages" in any of:
    c:\go\src\pages (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Users\wcfuser\go\src\pages (from $GOPATH)

What in the world have I done wrong here?

Comment: Is GOPATH also set in your *User* env variables?

Comment: Hi Adrian. No it isn't.

Comment: Have you restarted the shell, logged out/in, whatever it takes for Windows to initialize the command line with the new environment?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `GOPATH` is not correctly set on Windows settings. I'm not a Windows user myself though, so I may be wrong.

[Here's the official guide on how to do it.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#windows)

That being said, keep in mind you only really need to set it if you want something different that the default. You can leave the defaults and just clone the projects you want inside the correct `GOPATH`, for instance:

```
cd C:\Users\foo\go\src
mkdir -p github.com\caarlos0
cd github.com\caarlos0
git clone https://github.com/caarlos0/env.git
```

Or just:

```
go get github.com/caarlos0/env
cd C:\Users\foo\go\src\github.com\caarlos0\env
```

Any way you decide to go, you'll need to have most projects inside this `GOPATH` structure. It is a bit confusing at first, so don't trip about it :)

Comment: The [current documentation](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) no longer even mentions using GOPATH. If someone is starting out, it would probably be better to learn how modules work first.

Comment: True that, but if you need to work on a project that does not use go modules yet, you need to be aware of the GOPATH stuff... that's why I tried to explain it still...